# How do I invoke a class from my Main method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a user input a couple of numbers and I show the output using newNumerator = in.nextDouble(); but I'm asked to change Fraction newNumerator to a double and if I do, I than have to change it to Fraction.
What am I missing?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class FractionTest {

 public static void main(String[] args){

    Fraction newNumerator;
    Fraction newDenominator;


    newNumerator = new Fraction();
    newDenominator = new Fraction();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a numerator: ");
    newNumerator = in.nextDouble(); // I get an error here

    System.out.println("Please enter a denominator: ");  
    newDenominator = in.nextDouble(); // I get an error here

    in.close();
 }
}
```

The above is my Main() and the following is my class.

```
public class Fraction {

public double numeratorAnswer;
public double denominatorAnswer;

public Fraction() {

}

public double getNumeratorAnswer(){

    return numeratorAnswer;
}

public void setNumeratorAnswer(double newNumerator){

    numeratorAnswer = newNumerator;
}

  public double getDenominatorAnswer(){

    return denominatorAnswer;
}

public void setDenominatorAnswer(double newDenominator){

    denominatorAnswer = newDenominator;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put a `double` into a `Fraction` variable instead of putting the `double` in the `Fraction`.

To fix this, use a single `Fraction` value and call `setNumeratorAnswer` and `setDenominatorAnswer` with your `in.nextDouble()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a double value to an object of Fraction class in following statements:

```
newNumerator = in.nextDouble(); // I get an error here

System.out.println("Please enter a denominator: ");  
newDenominator = in.nextDouble(); // I get an error here
```

As this cast is not possible so you need to take the double inputs and then assign Fraction class numeratorAnswer and denominatorAnswer attributes. Something like this:

```
double dnewNumerator = in.nextDouble(); 

System.out.println("Please enter a denominator: ");  
double dnewDenominator = in.nextDouble(); 
newNumerator.setNumeratorAnswer(dnewNumerator);
newNumerator.setDenominatorAnswer(dnewDenominator);
```

I am not sure what exactly you want to do with the inputs so not adding much code here, just showing how you can set the Fraction class attributes. I don't thin you need two Fraction objects

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the order of your code a little to:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a numerator: ");
newNumerator = new Fraction(in.nextDouble());

System.out.println("Please enter a denominator: ");
newDenominator = new Fraction(in.nextDouble());
```

And after this, add a constructor to your Fraction class to receive double.

```
//Update your constructor as..
public Fraction(double numerator, double denominator) {
    this.numeratorAnswer= numerator;
    this.denominatorAnswer= denominator;
}
```

I guess you probably knows why get the errors as stated in your commented codes. The error is caused by giving variable of different data type.

Your `newNumerator` and `newDenominator` are by datatype of `Fraction`. Thus you can't use it to accept double values.

In the code sample I gave, you receive the double values and pass these values into the Fraction class's numerator & denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a `double` into a `fraction`.  You need to take the values of the `double` and assign it to the `fraction` object.

I hope this helps answer your question.